# GSAP/TweenLite/TweenMax onComplete not firing when using updateTo on onUpdate

Tags: actionscript-3, tween, gsap

onComplete not firing when using updateTo on onUpdate. if I remove updateTo line onComplete is triggered as it should.

I am using latest update of GSAP.

```
private function fingerLoop():void 
{
   // Set the gotoPlanet var

   TweenMax.to(finger, 1, { x:gotoPlanet.x, y:gotoPlanet.y, onComplete:fingerLoop, onUpdate:moveFinger, onUpdateParams:["{self}", gotoPlanet] });
}

private function moveFinger(tween, gotoPlanet):void 
{
  tween.updateTo({x:gotoPlanet.x, y:gotoPlanet.y}, false);
}
```

Comment: This question would probably be better suited on the greensock forums

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can add an `onComplete` handler to the `updateTo()` call, like this:

```
tween.updateTo({x:gotoPlanet.x, y:gotoPlanet.y, onComplete:fingerLoop}, false);
```

Comment: Good idea. I found a workaround. I kill tween when object is near to target object and start it again heading to another obj.  Your way seems very interesting. I will try it.

Comment: That didn't work. 
Greensock has plugin for club members called DinamcProps for this kind of tasks. So I think this availability is blocked in class files.